# What is the general approach to implement the serial number and activation protection for Java Application?

Tags: java

I want to create a Java Desktop Application and want to employ some mechanism to protect my software from illegal copy. What is the general best approach to implement the serial number and activation protection for Java Application? If the user can activate the software correctly, where to store the activation info?

Thanks.

Comment: Here are some hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piracy

Comment: Short answer: It's very, very difficult -- if not impossible -- to keep a determined user from pirating your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can almost be only one answer: On your server, together with a significant part of your algorithm(s). If all the code has to be on the client, then all that could work is

1. Trusted computing (ultimately a hardware barrier)
2. Steganography (obfuscating, scattering, hiding, deceiving, ...)

Comment: Does this mean the app will always require connecting to the server in order to run? Or is it that your answer does not cover the "where to store the activation info?" part?

Comment: @Martinho: If a significant part of the algorithm is on the server, then yes, at least for executing those parts, the app will have to be connected to the server. For the (many) cases, where that's not possible, I supplied the comparatively weak alternatives I know about.

Comment: @chris_l: I disagree with the "comparatively weak" thing. They all seem equally weak, but the online approach can be a nuissance for legitimate users, making it slightly weaker. One can always "fix" the application, no matter if the keys are checked locally or remotely. Having said that, there are no better solutions...

Comment: @chris_l: thank you for your answer, is it possible to use some runtime compilation technique to compile the activation info with some class objects into a brand new class or a jar file which must be used by the main program?

Comment: @Martinho: I don't fully understand, and I am quite sure, that the server solution is a lot stronger (while I'd still like to hear other arguments) Let's assume for a moment, I have devised an ingenious algorithm, let's call it `f`, and I only offer it as a service. The client supplies `x`, the server returns `f(x)`. I don't ever deploy `f` to the client, and users will have to log in to get the benefit of calculating `f(x)`. This is an abstract example - to make it more concrete, take Google's geolocation service for example. They don't have to deploy the entire database to the client...

Comment: @chris_l: pretend a pirate replaces the routine that calls the remote service with one that always returns true. Just like what he would do if the check was made locally.

Comment: @ziang: If the main program runs on the client, then the user can simply replace the main program, and you won't have gained very much. Or do you mean, that the main program will run on the server? If yes, then you don't need special compilation techniques! In that case, simply send a hashed value of a password - or maybe a client certificate - to the server.

Comment: @Martinho: 100% correct, absolutely correct thinking - but I'm not talking about an algorithm that just checks the user's credentials or something. In this case, what you're saying must be underlined and be repeated in bold, and I couldn't agree more! But I'm talking about something very different: A significant *part of the program* must reside on the server. Something, that the user needs (think about calculating a Raytracing picture for example).

Comment: @chris_l: I agree, if the program is split between the server and the client, you can have a certain level of security. That may not be an option for many projects, though, if you factor both development and server costs. I think the old maxim of "spend time improving your product, not securing it" wins in the end.